# Usage of '+=' in c

Tags: c, operators, assignment-operator, pre-increment

I don't understand why, on this code, 'b+=' return 6 instead of 5. The operation on right-end of operator '+=', should be 0.

1. i/2 = 4
2. a-4= 0

So Operator '+=' should just add: 0.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  int a=4, i=8;
  int b;
  
  b=++a; 
  printf("%i\n",b);

  b+=a-i/2;
  printf("%i\n",b);

}
```

Just using theory of sintax

Comment: Do you know what `++a` does?

Comment: That's C, which is correctly tagged. And there's no `=+` operator. `b=++a` is really `b = ++a`.

Comment: As for `b+=a-i/2` it's the same as `b += a - i / 2`, which is the same as `b = b + (a - (i / 2))`.

Comment: You might be more enlightened if you print the value of `a` too.

Comment: a++ and ++a is the shortcut for a = a + 1 so the value actually changes, the difference between them is post-increment changes the value of the variable a after statement executed and pre-increment changes the value of the variable a before assigning it to variable b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After this statement

```
b=++a;
```

`b` and `a` will be equal to `5` due to the prefix increment operator `++`.

From the C Standard (6.5.3.1 Prefix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 The value of the operand of the prefix ++ operator is incremented.
> The result is the new value of the operand after incrementation. The
> expression ++E is equivalent to (E+=1)

So in this compound assignment statement

```
b+=a-i/2;
```

that may be rewritten like

```
b = b + a - i/2;
```

you have

```
b = 5 + 5 - 4
```

So as a result you have `b` is equal to `6`.

You could get the expected by you result if to initialize the variable `b` by zero

```
int b = 0;
```

and if to remove this statement

b=++a;

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `b=++a;`, a is incremented. Its value becomes 5. Then afterward, `a-i/2` is `5-8/2` then 1.